# How to parse a typical restful api uri request, and call the needed functions

Tags: php, rest

The question is: How do one parse a typical restful api request, and call the needed functions?

In order to clarify with an example see below:

**Example requests HTTP GET method:**

```
www.example.com/people/ - return all people in the database

www.example.com/people/12 - return the person with the userID of 12
```

**Example requests HTTP POST method:**

```
www.example.com/people/bob/johansen - creates a new person bob johansen
```

**Collect HTTP method and do something from here.**

```
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
if ($method == 'POST') {
    // this is the place im unsure of
} elseif ($method == 'GET') {
    // this is the place im unsure of
} elseif ($method == 'PUT') {
   // this is the place im unsure of
} elseif ($method == 'DELETE') {
   // this is the place im unsure of
} else {
    // Method unknown
}
```

I would like to know how the code looks like that parse the urls above. Clearly the 2 get methods are either 2 different function calls, or maybe the same. So that is my question:

**How do one parse a typical restful api request, and call the needed functions?**

Comment: Why don't you use a framework that has a built-in router to handle the different type of requests? Even something small like Slim will help you a lot.

Comment: I agree with @Drown. Even if you insist on writing this yourself, just look at a microframework or router for minimal examples.